# How to configure workspace with egit/eclipse so my changes go to branch on fork

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github, egit

I'm working with a github project that I don't own.  I originally cloned this project to my Mars.1 workspace for initial examination and debugging.

Note that I posted a similar question to the EGit forum at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1715162/#msg_1715162.

I now know of at least two sets of changes I want to make.  I've forked the original project in github, and I've created a branch in that fork in github that I intend to implement the first set of changes in.

What's unclear to me at this point is how to configure my Eclipse workspace properly so that my changes that I make now will get committed and pushed into the branch on my fork.  I'll eventually submit a PR(s) for these changes, but I'll also be seeding a separate git repo with this resulting codebase.

All I could figure out at this point was creating a remote in eclipse that points to my fork.  I only defined the push config at this point, not the fetch config (I'm the only one working on this for now).

I don't understand the required next steps.  I've read through the EGit user guide, but that isn't helping me answer this question.  I've asked about this on non-Eclipse forums, but they all tell me to ignore Eclipse and do it at the command line, or expound for paragraphs on what I apparently don't know about the structure of a git repo.

Comment: Did you read the User Guide on [Remote Repositories](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/Remote)?

Comment: Yes, and I just paged through it again just to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from Matthias Sohn on EGit team, I've been able to move forward with this.

The key thing I was missing was that I was only setting the "Push" config on the remote.  The "Fetch" config was more important, ironically.  When the remote got the Fetch config, it pulled down the info about my branch, which I was then able to switch to.  I was then able to make my changes, commit, and push to my branch on github.  I also created the PR to the original project.

One thing with EGit that made this harder for me to figure out was the difference between creating a "Fetch" config on the Remote on first creation, compared to afterwards, if setting the "Push" config on first creation.  You'll note that when you first create a Remote, you have a choice of setting the "Push" config or the "Fetch" config, but not both.  It turns out that if you select the "Fetch" config, it gives you a reasonable default for an initial mapping, but if you create the "Fetch" afterwards, you have to manually create a mapping, and it doesn't suggest the reasonable default.